# Typescript interface declaration for form event

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript.  I have a react component where I declare the following form control event:

```
interface FormControlEvent extends React.FormEvent {
    currentTarget: HTMLInputElement;
}
```

Why do I get the following error with my React.FormEvent highlight in red by TSLint:

```
[ts] Generic type 'FormEvent<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
interface FormEvent<T>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the type of `FormEvent`. The compiler is complaining that the type `FormEvent<T>` is a generic type, but you have not specified what that generic type is.

```
interface FormControlEvent extends React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement> {
    currentTarget: HTMLInputElement;
}
```